# AS2 getAscii doesn't get Caps Lock in Google Chrome

Tags: flash, google-chrome, actionscript, keyboard, actionscript-2

I'm using Flash AS2 (no other option) to get the letters typed by a user.

It seems that in Google Chrome, the Ascii code that I get is different than usual.

I'm testing with typing "P" after activating "Caps Lock". I'm tracing what Key.getCode() and Key.getAscii() return.

In Firefox or IE or even standalone player :

- Caps Lock on => Key.getCode() : 80 ; Key.getAscii() : 80
- Caps Lock off => Key.getCode() : 80 ; Key.getAscii() : 112

In Chrome, it seems that the Caps Lock is always off :

- Caps Lock on => Key.getCode() : 80 ; Key.getAscii() : 112
- Caps Lock off => Key.getCode() : 80 ; Key.getAscii() : 112

As a result, I cannot get if Caps Lock is on or off on Chrome...

Has anyone seen this problem before?

---

EDIT : complementary tests :

Note that the tests have been made with a french AZERTY keyboard

Google Chrome

1

- pad =>   Key.getCode()=97 -> a ; Key.getAscii()=49 -> 1
- normal =>    Key.getCode()=49 -> 1 ; Key.getAscii()=49 -> 1
- shift =>     Key.getCode()=49 -> 1 ; Key.getAscii()=33 -> !
- caps =>  Key.getCode()=49 -> 1 ; Key.getAscii()=49 -> 1

a

- normal =>    Key.getCode()=65 -> A ; Key.getAscii()=97 -> a
- shift => Key.getCode()=65 -> A ; Key.getAscii()=65 -> A
- caps =>  Key.getCode()=65 -> A ; Key.getAscii()=97 -> a

Others

1

- pad =>   Key.getCode()=97 -> a ; Key.getAscii()=49 -> 1
- normal =>    Key.getCode()=49 -> 1 ; Key.getAscii()=38 -> &
- shift =>     Key.getCode()=49 -> 1 ; Key.getAscii()=38 -> &
- caps =>  Key.getCode()=49 -> 1 ; Key.getAscii()=38 -> &

a

- normal =>    Key.getCode()=65 -> A ; Key.getAscii()=97 -> a
- shift => Key.getCode()=65 -> A ; Key.getAscii()=65 -> A
- caps =>  Key.getCode()=65 -> A ; Key.getAscii()=65 -> A

Comment: I haven't seen this exact behavior, but I have seen wmode="transparent" having similar side effects on keyboard input. So if you are using a wmode other than the default ("window"), it could be worth trying to change that.

Comment: Also, is the user input in a TextField? If it is, are you sure you need to use Key.getAscii(), and that you cannot simply look at what's in the TextField?

Comment: The wmode is normal and it's not in a textfield :( I specifficaly need to get the key that is typed.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your code based on if the Caps Lock key [`isToggled()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/help.html?content=00001148.html) or not.

You can add `32` to any capital letter to get its lower case match (or use `String.toLowerCase()` ) and you can subtract `32` from any lower case letter to get the upper case match (or use `String.toUpperCase()` ).

```
//this code would change a whole string, but you can 
//do it with individually entered characters
if(Key.isToggled(Key.CAPSLOCK)){
    String.fromCharCode(Key.getCode()-32);
}else{
    String.fromCharCode(Key.getCode());
}
```

Comment: This solution partially meets my needs : as you can see, when I type "1" with the keys over the letters, normal & shift are reversed when I'm with Chrome and in other players.

Comment: You could use a regex statement to only do the changes to alphabetical characters.  There is no native regex support in as2 but there is a library that gives some functionality.  http://www.jurjans.lv/flash/RegExp.html  Does that help?